# What version of JBoss Enterprise Edition supports JDK7?

Tags: java

I need to determine what version, if any, of JBoss Enterprise Edition supports JDK7. It is unclear from the RedHat documentation and forums if there is currently any support for JDK7. I do believe support for JDK6 is certified as of JBoss 5.1.1 Enterprise Edition.

Answer (score 1):

JBoss 5.1 EAP is compatible with JDK 1.7 as can be confirmed here:

https://access.redhat.com/site/articles/113083#Compat_5